# Regular expression does not work as intended

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to match a Python-style single- and multi-line strings.
Here's what I've come up wtih so far:

```
public const string PythonString = @"(?<string>('''[^(''')]*''')|(""""""[^("""""")]*"""""")|("".*"")|('.*'))";
```

It fails when you have, for example, a single `"` in a triple-`"` matching string:

```
"""
msg = "Nothing in this file is used in w3af. This was a test that was truncated by my personal\
lack of interest in using encryption here, my lack of time and the main reason: I'm lazy ;)\
Also, pyrijndael was only used here, so I removed the dependency, which was a problem for debian."
raise Exception(msg)
"""
```

Here, the `"` in the string forces the regex to stop the match after the first triple-`"`, instead of matching the whole block.
How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you show what's your expected output for a few sample inputs?

Comment: It is a common misconception that placing a sequence of chars into a negated char class will result in matching a sequence of chars other than the defined sequence. In fact, `[^(''')]*` = `[^)(']`. So, you need `@"(?s)(?<string>('''[^']*(?:'(?!'')[^']*)*''')|(""""""[^""]*(?:""(?!"""")[^""]*)*"""""")|(""[^""\\]*(?:\\.[^""\\]*)*"")|('[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'))"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you! It works. Could you explain what `(?:'(?!'')[^']*)*` does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a common misconception that placing a sequence of chars into a negated character class will result in matching a sequence of chars other than the specified sequence. In fact, `[^(''')]*` = `[^)(']*`.

You need to use lookaheads here together with negated character classes:

```
@"(?s)(?<string>('''[^']*(?:'(?!'')[^']*)*''')|(""""""[^""]*(?:""(?!"""")[^""]*)*"""""")|(""[^""\\]*(?:\\.[^""\\]*)*"")|('[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'))"
```

The `[^']*(?:'(?!'')[^']*)*` matches

- `[^']*` - any 0+ chars other than `'`
- `(?:'(?!'')[^']*)*` - 0+ sequences of:

  - `'(?!'')` - a `'` not followed with two `'` chars
  - `[^']*` - any 0+ chars other than `'`.

When matching single quote literals, you need to account for escaped chars, so you need `[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*` in between the quotes inside the pattern:

- `[^'\\]*` - any 0+ chars other than `'` and `\`
- `(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*` - zero or more sequences of

  - `\\.` - a `\` followed with any char
  - `[^'\\]*` - any 0+ chars other than `'` and `\`